# product of end equal to end of product

Tags: category-theory

In the theory of ends, is it true in general that the end of a product is equal to the product of the ends? If not, then what are sufficient conditions for it to be true?

For instance, if $F,G,H,I\in[\mathcal{C}^{\text{op}},\text{Set}]$, is it true that

$$\int_Y \text{Set}(F(Y),G(Y))\times \int_Y\text{Set}(H(Y),I(Y)) \cong
\int_Y \text{Set}(F(Y),G(Y))\times\text{Set}(H(Y),I(Y))$$
I seem to have seen steps like this done in a few places but haven't found a justification for it. Does one prove this from 'first principles' i.e. the definitions of ends and products, or is there a more immediate way to see this is true?

Comment: I stumbled upon a similar question, for a different reason (trying to compute the Kan extension $Lan_{F+G}(T)$). I _think_ that a sufficient condition for the isomorphism to hold is that the functor $\Delta^o\times\Delta : A^o\times A \to A^o\times A^o \times A \times A$ is cofinal; this happens when $A$ is [sifted and cosifted](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sifted+category), a sufficient condition for which is that $A$ has both products and coproducts. Can anyone confirm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Limits commute with limits and ends are particular kinds of limits. But you have to take into account the correct formula for this, that is, given a functor $L : {\cal I}\times{\cal J}\to \cal C$, the limits
$$\textstyle
\lim_{\cal I}\lim_{\cal J} L\quad \lim_{\cal J}\lim_{\cal I} L\quad \lim_{\cal I\times J} L
$$ are all isomorphic (even more precisely, one exists iff all three exist and they are canonically isomorphic objects).

So, in general no, it is false; the integration variable is mute, so the red $Y$ and the blue $Y$ in the product of integrals
$$
\int_{\color{red} Y} \text{Set}(F({\color{red} Y}),G({\color{red} Y}))\times \int_{\color{blue} Y}\text{Set}(H({\color{blue} Y}),I({\color{blue} Y}))
$$ have to be treated as different. The best you can say thus is that
$$
\int_{\color{red} Y} \text{Set}(F({\color{red} Y}),G({\color{red} Y}))\times \int_{\color{blue} Y}\text{Set}(H({\color{blue} Y}),I({\color{blue} Y}))\cong\int_{\color{red} Y\color{blue} Y} \text{Set}(F({\color{red} Y}),G({\color{red} Y}))\times \text{Set}(H({\color{blue} Y}),I({\color{blue} Y}))
$$ to further reduce this to be equal to
$$
\int_{\color{green} Y} \text{Set}(F({\color{green} Y}),G({\color{green} Y}))\times \text{Set}(H({\color{green} Y}),I({\color{green} Y}))
$$ you need further assumptions on $\cal C$.

Comment: It would be clearer to separate variables instead of the coloring them, at least in an additional formula.

Comment: thanks for the response Fosco, I've got a couple follow up questions.
The first one is general - you mention 'canonically isomorphic' objects. What is the precise meaning of 'canonical'? Am I correct in thinking 'canonical isomorphism' = 'natural isomorphism' in the context of category theory? Do we also need uniqueness?

A quick browse of some threads (e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19644/what-is-the-definition-of-canonical) seems to suggest 'canonical' can be used to mean a variety of things.

Comment: A second question is, does the specific case
$$\int_Y\text{Set}(\mathcal{C}(Y,X),GY)\times\text{Set}(\mathcal{C}(Y,Z),GY)\cong
\int_Y \text{Set}(\mathcal{C}(Y,X),GY)\times \int_Y \text{Set}(\mathcal{C}(Y,Z),GY)$$
hold?

Comment: RE your second question, the RHS is just $GX\times GZ$; I don't think this equals the LHS in general.

Comment: RE your first question, yes, "canonical" can be intended in various ways; in the case above, it means "isomorphic via a unique natural [in $L$] isomorphism"

Comment: Right, well it seems I've misunderstood something somewhere.
One last question then - have I made a mistake in thinking 
$$\int_Y \text{Set}(\mathcal{C}(Y,X))+\mathcal{C}(Y,Z),GY)
\cong
\int_Y \text{Set}(\mathcal{C}(Y,X),GY)\times \text{Set}(\mathcal{C}(Y,Z),GY)
$$?
And if so, what is the strategy for getting rid of the $+$

Comment: The problem is: there are 3 $Y$'s in the functor you are trying to integrate, whereas coends can be taken just for "balanced" expressions where you have a functor that depends on $Y$ covariantly $n$ times, and contravariantly $n$ times; if you want to extend this to "unbalanced tensors", what you get is [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.13881).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117911/discussion-between-merk-zockerborg-and-fosco).